# Can chinese tablet be used without a battery?

Tags: battery

I have a Chinese tablet xpad xpod 7" tablet, bought it 2 months ago, I am already having problem with battery, it is discharging too quickly, so I want to operate my tablet without battery, simply by plugging in the power adapter.

1. Can I operate tablet without battery?
2. Will direct use of power adapter negatively affect the tablet?

I do not need battery anyway, it is an unnecessary expense for me, it will wear out, it is a hassle, and I don't need it because I need to use the tablet in my home only.

I have tried to google for this, but no detailed reliable answers, it appears to be a grey area, I need expert opinion.

Comment: Instead of asking google or here, how about simply trying this? What have you got to lose? So far l've seen only one device where you could remove/exchange the battery while running & plugged in, and that is the Openmoko Freerunner.

Answer (score 0):

1. I believe most of the Chinese tablet can do that.
2. There is no negative effect but it might overheat.